# IE - "use strict" SCRIPT1014: Invalid character

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

When I run my web on IE it fails to load everything and give an error of

> SCRIPT1014: Invalid character

on

> "use strict";

I have no issue on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, Opera but only on IE. What is the cause of this error ??

Comment: have you by any chance resolved this issue? It's happening for me as well in my Vue.js project

Answer (score 0):

"use strict" Defines that JavaScript code should be executed in "strict mode", this statement doesn't really change anything. With strict mode, you can not, for example, use undeclared variables. More detail information, please check [JavaScript Use Strict](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp)

So, please check your code and modify the Invalid character.

Besides, perhaps you are using [ECMAScript 6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp) syntax. Since, ECMAScript 6 doesn't support IE browser, you could use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) to translate the code to ES5 syntax.